# Is it safe if detached std::thread uses object that went out of scope?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Imagine that I start a `std::thread` which runs a member function of an object. What happens if that object goes out of scope in main function where I created the thread?

```
class ThreadClass {
    public:
    ThreadClass(int i) : _a(i) {
    }

    void foo() {
        sleep(10);
        std::cout << "Is it safe here? " << _a << std::endl;
    }
    int _a;
};

int main() {
    {
        ThreadClass obj(3);
        std::thread t(&ThreadClass::foo, &obj);
        t.detach();
    }

    // Here obj goes out of scope
    // What about thread?

    sleep(20);
    return 0;
}
```

Would be this an undefined behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is undefined behavior. More specifically, you will end up with a segmentation fault because the thread is trying to access some object which no longer exists. So here is what I'd suggest:

- Declare the `obj` somewhere that will not go out of scope during the lifetime of any thread(Probably global).
- Pass by value instead of a reference.
- Create an object using `new` and pass the pointer to the thread using `std::shared_ptr`. (In this case you will have to make sure the thread calls the `delete` operation, to avoid a memory leak).

Comment: So, if I would call as std::thread t(&ThreadClass::foo, obj); would be OK?

Comment: Yes it should be fine.

Comment: “you will end up with a segmentation fault” — you *may*. What actually happens is really unclear and depends on a lot of things. Amongst all the possibilities, the example could also run and yield the output “"Is it safe here? 3”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Indeed, it was giving me the right output! But I knew that this does not mean more than to be lucky.

Answer (score 6):

No, that code isn’t safe. The `thread` holds a non-owning reference to the object (via a copy of the pointer `&obj`). Once the object goes out of scope, that’s a dangling reference.

Comment: I know that this answer deserved to be accepted as answer. thanks!

Comment: @MertMertce Then accept it, it's more concise and correct compared to the other.

Comment: @user657267 Eh, the other answer is fine — it offers solutions.